# Inconsistent 3DMark CPU Score

Tags: windows-10, overclocking, benchmarking, amd-ryzen, 3dmark

I completed a new Ryzen based PC build, and have been trying to optimize it by doing some minor overclocking.  While doing so, I've noticed that I'm getting inconsistent 3dMark CPU results that are driving my average down.  On a favorable run, the report reads that my processor is utilizing 1/32 Physical/Logical cores, while in the more common case the summary indicates that it was only utilizing 1/16 Physical/Logical cores. Does anyone know what could be causing this or if I'm missing something?

**Benchmarks:**

- Bad Run - https://www.3dmark.com/spy/24360790
- Good Run - https://www.3dmark.com/spy/24342340

There's about a ~8 CPU based FPS difference in the two results.

**Hardware:**

- AMD Ryzen 9 5950X
- Gigabyte Aurous Master
- EVGA 3080 TI
- 64 GB Trident DDR4 @ 3600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue here, the inconsistent results were a result of BIOs resets while tweaking causing AMD Ryzen Master's custom BIOs settings to be reset.  I had AMD Ryzen Master's 'Gaming Mode' enabled on a few runs, since I was ignorant as to what it was actually doing. Apparently 'Gaming Mode' cuts the number of active cores in half for compatibility with legacy games.  This isn't good when running benchmarks, obviously, and basically results in half the CPU score you would have gotten with all cores enabled.

TLDR:  Make sure Ryzen Master's 'Gaming Mode' isn't enabled when running benchmarks, use 'Creator Mode' if you want to use the tool for overclocking.